# str not a callable object python

Tags: python, string, object, callable

I am a bit curious as to why my code is causing this error?
 Can someone show me some insight as a way to fix this and the reason it is raising it?

Error:

```
chunk += " " (16 - len(chunk) % 16)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

My Code:

```
def upload(item):
    with open(item, "rb") as fp:
        while True:
            chunk = fp.read(64*1024)

            if len(chunk) == 0:
                break
            elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                chunk += " " (16 - len(chunk) % 16)

            self.s.send(encrypt(self.key, chunk, self.iv))

    self.s.send("DONE")
    self.update()
```

Comment: You forgot the `*` after `" "`

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I use the exact same code in my other script and it raises no error why is it just now doing it?

Comment: Well, maybe in your other script erroneous line is never reached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `chunk += " " (16 - len(chunk) % 16)` to:

```
 chunk += " " * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)
```

If you put nothing there it means that `" "` is callable and you are trying to call it with `16 - len(chunk) % 16` parameter.